# Including webpack helper methods and polyfills only in main bundle

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, polyfills, transpiler

I'm using webpack to bundle React but I still need to transpile our legacy code base written in plain javascript.  I've gotten it to work so far but I noticed that since webpack treats every javascript file as an individual bundle it is also injecting its helper methods and polyfills in every file. It would be best if those were only included in the main javascript file and that way reducing the size of the subsequent files.

Is there a way to achieve this?

If anyone's curious how I'm transpiling each legacy js file individually.

```
            glob.sync(PATH).forEach((file) => {
                    exports.push({
                        entry: file,
                        output: {
                            path: path.resolve(__dirname),
                            filename: file,
                        },
                        module: {
                            rules: [
                                {
                                    test: /\.js$/,
                                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                                    loader: 'babel-loader'
                                }]
                        },
                        devtool: 'eval',
                    });
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a way so here's how my set up is currenlty looking.

**.babelrc**  "useBuiltIns": "entry" makes it so you polyfills (and helper methods too?) are only inserted when requested.  In other words when you call "import" at the top of the file.  This allows me to create a polyfill.js file with nothing in it other than **import "core-js";** which turns into a much larger file with all the polyfills I need.

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "corejs": "3.6.4",
        "useBuiltIns": "entry",
        "targets": {
          "ie": "11"
        }
      }
    ],
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    "@babel/transform-runtime"
  ],
  "sourceType": "unambiguous"
}
```

the **webpack** configuration for these files looks like (the exports collection is ultimately assigned to module.exports).

```
            glob
                .sync(PATH)
                .forEach((file) => {

                        let config = {
                            entry: file,
                            output: {
                                path: path.resolve(__dirname),
                                filename: file,
                            },
                            module: {
                                rules: [
                                    {
                                        test: /\.js$/,
                                        exclude: /node_modules/,
                                        loader: 'babel-loader'
                                    }],
                            }
                        };

                        exports.push(config)
            });
```

needless to say polyfill.js is the first script called in my html.